# Dynamically .load()ed elements are not queryable

Tags: jquery, iframe, load, carousel, vimeo

I have a main html file and a number of **iframe** elements stored in the external html files which are only loaded on-demand after user clicks on one of the navigator's buttons.

```
$('#carousel_01').load('content_01.html');
```

Each **iframe's** **src** attribute is pointing to a Vimeo video.
To each Vimeo video I attach an Event Listener function that monitors a state of the video and triggers a certain action within a main html document (div animation mostly).

The problem is: After the external iframe is loaded into the main html file it is not getting registered as a part of the document itself.
If I query all the iframes within the main html document using

```
var vimeoPlayers = document.querySelectorAll('iframe'), player;
```

only previously loaded iframes are returned. The ones that were loaded dynamically are not in the list (while still being displayed and visible on the main page).
Without being able to query loaded iframes I can't attach the event listeners to video.
How can I enforce an update of the main html document so it recognizes the imported (loaded) iframes?

Comment: `.load()` is asynchronous, are you waiting for the AJAX call to complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since AJAX is asynchronous, you need to update the variable in the callback function:

```
$('#carousel_01').load('content_01.html', function() {
    vimeoPlayers = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
});
```